# Winform UserControl update while not visible

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, draw

I have a tabControl in a Winform application. The user is able to change settings that will impact each tab visually, and I need to get each tabs as images.

I'm trying to understand why/how some controls are updating even if not visible and some other don't.

Is there a way to force an existing UserControl to update/redraw even if not visible so that Control.DrawToBitmap(...) gets a valid image?

I created an example with a Chart and a FlowLayoutPanel to explain what I mean and to make sure I could reproduce the issue I have.

**In the example below:**

- The image created from the FlowLayoutPanel is only correct if it was updated and visible before DrawToBitmap is called.
- The image from the Chart is alway up to date even if updated when not visible.

**Questions:**
How does it work with one control and not the other?
How could I ensure the FlowLayoutPanel has the same behavior as the Chart?

**(EDIT) I have tried a few things without success:**

- Suspend/Resume layout when updating
- call Refresh / Update / Invalidate on the layout that do not update as expected

Here is a gif showing that the chart get updated even when not visible but not the FlowLayoutPanel:
[image: Here is a gif showing that the chart get updated even when not visible but not the FlowLayoutPanel]

Here is the code of this example:

```
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WinFormsDrawToBitmapTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int legendCount = 1;
        ViewModel viewModel;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new ViewModel();
            cartesianChart1.Series = viewModel.Series;
            updateLegend(this.flowLayoutPanel1);
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = await Task.Run(() => getImg3());
            this.pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
            this.pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            { this.pictureBox1.Image = bitmap; });
        }

        private Bitmap getImg3()
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.cartesianChart1.Width, this.cartesianChart1.Height + this.flowLayoutPanel1.Height);
            Bitmap chart = new Bitmap(this.cartesianChart1.Width, this.cartesianChart1.Height);
            Bitmap legend = new Bitmap(this.flowLayoutPanel1.Width, this.flowLayoutPanel1.Height);
            this.cartesianChart1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.cartesianChart1.DrawToBitmap(chart, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.cartesianChart1.Size));
            });
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.flowLayoutPanel1.DrawToBitmap(legend, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size));
            });

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.DrawImage(legend, 0, 0);
                g.DrawImage(chart, 0, legend.Height);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            viewModel.Data.Add(r.Next(0, 10));
            legendCount++;
            updateLegend(this.flowLayoutPanel1);
        }

        private void updateLegend(FlowLayoutPanel flow)
        {
            flow.Controls.Clear();
            Color[] colorList = new Color[]
            {
                Color.FromArgb(15, 1, 215),
                Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0),
                Color.FromArgb(0, 176, 80),
                Color.FromArgb(112, 48, 160)
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < legendCount; i++)
            {
                //flow.Controls.Add(new LegendLabel($"Label {i}", colorList[i % colorList.Length]));
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Name = $"Button {i}";
                btn.TabIndex = 0;
                btn.Text = $"Button {i}";
                flow.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<double> Data { get; set; }
        public List<LineSeries<double>> Series { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Data = new ObservableCollection<double>();
            Data.Add(1); Data.Add(2); Data.Add(5); Data.Add(4);
            Series = new List<LineSeries<double>>();
            Series.Add(new LineSeries<double> { Values = Data, Fill = null });
        }
    }
}
```

With the associated .Designer.cs in case it helps

```
namespace WinFormsDrawToBitmapTest
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.cartesianChart1 = new LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinForms.CartesianChart();
            this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPage2.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1042, 24);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(167, 0);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "Change Tab1";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Get Tab1 as Image in Tab 2";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // tabControl1
            // 
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
            this.tabControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
            this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1042, 585);
            this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // tabPage1
            // 
            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.cartesianChart1);
            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel1);
            this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 24);
            this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1034, 557);
            this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // cartesianChart1
            // 
            this.cartesianChart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 116);
            this.cartesianChart1.Name = "cartesianChart1";
            this.cartesianChart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1018, 435);
            this.cartesianChart1.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // flowLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 6);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1018, 100);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // tabPage2
            // 
            this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 24);
            this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
            this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1034, 557);
            this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.tabPage2.Text = "tabPage2";
            this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1028, 551);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1042, 609);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private Panel panel2;
        private Button button1;
        private TabControl tabControl1;
        private TabPage tabPage1;
        private TabPage tabPage2;
        private PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;
        private LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WinForms.CartesianChart cartesianChart1;
        private Button button2;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: It might require a `Paint` event to be raised. Does it work as you want if you call `Refresh` on the relevant control first?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Thank you for this suggestion I have tested Refresh on each Controls as well as  Suspend/Resume Layout but it did not help sadly. How would you raise a paint event?

Comment: `Refresh` does raise a `Paint` event. Internally, it calls `Invalidate`, which tells the control to repaint in its entirety on the next `Paint` event, and then `Update`, which raises a `Paint` event immediately.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Thank you for this clarification. Sadly, calling either or all of these (Refresh, Update, or even Invalidate) on flowLayoutPanel1 doesn't help.